# Monitoring Rundeck jobs using PRTG

Tags: rundeck, prtg

I have a Debian machine running Rundeck v4.11.0 and multiple jobs. I also have a Windows machine running PRTG v23.1.82.2175, monitoring various aspects of the Rundeck machine, like CPU, Memory, Disk etc. There is no agent installed on the Rundeck machine. PRTG allows you to define IP, user & pass of the Rundeck machine and it just autodiscovers and monitors it.

Sometimes jobs in Rundeck run longer than usual, or fail, and I want to monitor the status of those jobs also.

I was wondering if it's possible to use the PRTG server, to also monitor the status of the jobs running on Rundeck. I know you can have custom sensors on PRTG.

If anyone is using PRTG to monitor Rundeck jobs, an example of such a custom sensor would help out.

Comment: A custom PRTG bash sensor that gets info from the Rundeck API/Job results could help, take a look at these API examples: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k

Comment: yes, I think this will get the job done. thanks. add it an answer.

Comment: Great. Done :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom PRTG bash script sensor that gets info from the Rundeck API/Job results could help, take a look at [these API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k) examples.